# Laravel 7 redirect() weird behavior

Tags: redirect, laravel-7

On laravel 6, my redirection works well

```
return redirect()->route('name');
```

The behavior is what I expected, but on laravel 7, the same code does not do the same thing.

Instead of having the redirection, I get a blank page with my url printed on it.

I have tried many ways by reading the Laravel 7 redirection doc (and also here, 2 topics about laravel 7 redirection), but always this blank page + the supposed redirect url, printed on it.

Thank you for reading and suggestion/help

Comment: Redirection should work the same on 6 and 7, you might have some differences in your code. Can you post the route definition? Is there something helpful in your Laravel log file? Does your target method maybe `dd($xyz)` or something?

Answer (score 0):

@kerbholz yes, you are right and thank your for your reply.

I found why... I have this simple instruction before,

`return route('name');`

And it did an implicite redirection on laraval 6 but no more on laravel 7, that's why I have a blank page, with the url printed on it;

Because the previous instruction returns only a string and nothing more...

Thank you